# Terraform prevent deletion of resource

Tags: terraform

I have the following resource that adds a secret to an Azure Key Vault

```
resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "mySecret" {
  name         = "mySecret"
  value        = "helloWorld"
  key_vault_id = DYANMIC_ID
  
  lifecycle {
            prevent_destroy = true
    }
}
```

When I run the terraform plan command on Key Vault 1 I wanted to create the Secret in the vault - and this is successful. When I execute the same statement again, but against Key Vault 2 it is attempting to delete the value from Key Vault 1. I would like Terraform to ignore the deletion. Is this possible?
At the end of the second execution, I would like my Secret in both Key Vault 1 and Key Vault 2.
Currently I get an error: "Instance cannot be destroyed".

Further, it would be ideal that if I changed the value of "value" it would update and not error.

Comment: If you are managing two different Key Vaults (1 & 2), then it may be wise to use two resource blocks.

Comment: I thought someone might say that...I have between 0 and 6 Vaults, but each need to be provisioned manually

Comment: You may want to import each manually created resource so each of them is represented in your state file. Terraform tracks each resource individually, so you have to tell it that some resources already exist through an import (if manual creation is truly a requirement).

Comment: How did you create/defined six `DYANMIC_ID`?

Comment: Add different vault providers using aliases, and use separate resources to maintain them. You can have 1 generate keys and have the others refer to those keys to populate in the additional vaults, unless you want distinct secrets for each vault.